# How to get a certain value in this XML file using XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<item>
 <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
 <media:group>
   <media:content url = "http://www.sample.com" rate = "0" />
   <media:content url = "http://www.sample1.com" rate = "1" />
   <media:content url = "http://www.sample2.com" rate = "2" />
 </media:group>
</item>
```

How do I get this value:

> http://www.sample2.com?

I tried using this code:

```
var query = from i in loadedData.Descendants("item")
 select new Site
 {
  Title = (string)i.Element("title"),
  Url = (string)i.Element(serv + "group").Elements(media + "content").Last()
 };
 site = query.ToList();
```

but the value of Url is "".
I also have this:

```
private static readonly XNamespace media = "http://www.sampleX.com/";
```

Comment: Try `Url = (string)i.Element(serv + "group").Elements(media + "content").Last().Attribute("url").Value;`

Comment: How can it match up the namespace with no `xmlns:media="http://www.sampleX.com/"` attribute declared anywhere in your XML? Is it declared on an element you aren't showing?

Comment: I think this is just a extract of an items list xml file with namespace declared anyhwere.

Comment: Batuu is right, I only showed a portion of the xml

Comment: Hi, would you like to mark the answer that helped you as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this LINQ query:

```
var list = loadedData.Descendants("item")
                     .Select(e => new Site() 
                                  {
                                   Title = e.Element("title")
                                            .Value, 
                                   Url = e.Descendants(media + "content")
                                          .Last()
                                          .Attribute("url")
                                          .Value
                                  })
                     .ToList();
```